# Get list of Google Fonts

Tags: php

I want to get list of google web fonts in select box to select a font. I am trying following function, but it gives the error.

**Code:**

```
function get_google_fonts() {
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=alpha";
    $result = json_response( $url );
        $font_list = array();
        foreach ( $result->items as $font ) {
            $font_list[] .= $font->family;          
        }
        return $font_list;  
}

function json_response( $url )  {
    $raw = file_get_contents( $url, 0, null, null );
    $decoded = json_decode( $raw );
    return $decoded;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP.
```

If I change the https to http, I get this error:

```
file_get_contents(http://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=alpha): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
```

I guess this is because of PHP settings on my server, which I am unable to change. So, is there any alternative way to get the font list from Google? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow https wraper you must have the `php_openssl` extension and enable `allow_url_include`

You can edit you `php.in`i to set these values :

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_include = On
```

If these values doesn't exist add these lines .

If you can't edit your php.ini file, then you can set in on the PHP file :

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');
ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');
```

You could also try using `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents`. `CURL` is much faster than `file_get_contents`

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=alpha";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yes, but if thats not the option. Is there any alternative way to get this?

Comment: Oh sorry. You can't edit php.ini right. Can you try with CURL

Comment: @user1251698 can you  try setting in PHP file like in my last edit : ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');
ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');

Comment: @Sabari: I don't understand, why does he need allow_url_include=On ? This has nothing to do with that directive.

Comment: It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think Webfonts deny access to non-browser agents. However you can use the [Webfont API](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api). In fact you need an API key, so once you get it, you'll use URLs like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

It's all documented [in the provided link](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api).

Answer (score 1):

Google requires SSL so make sure thats enabled on your server.

To fix this error, go to your php.ini file, find the line ;sslextension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api

```
    var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and its works

```php
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key='.$google_api_key;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$fonts = json_decode($result, true);
$asd =$fonts['items'];
$fonts_array = array();
foreach($asd as $as){
    $fonts_array[] = $as['family'];
}
var_dump($fonts_array);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).